# External Object Page Layout and Visualforce Pages

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, lightning-connect

I'm trying to add a Visualforce page (containing a table that references values from a native Salesforce object) to an external object's page layout. I have my controller class written and a simplified version of the VF page but when I try reference the standardController for the external object I'm getting an SObject type not supported error (in Eclipse):

VF PAGE HEADER:

```
apex:page standardController="CW_Order_Line__x" extensions="OrderLine_ShipToInfoCtrlExt" 
readOnly="true
```

RESULTANT ERROR:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Save error: Object type not
>   accessible. Please check permissions and make sure the object is not
>   in development mode: sObject type 'CW_Order_Line__x' is not
>   supported.. Original queryString was: 'SELECT ExternalId, Id FROM
>   CW_Order_Line__x WHERE id =
>   '000000000000000''    Order_Line_Item_Info.page   /Billing/src/pages  line
>   1 Force.com save problem

Wondering if anyone has come across this issue when working with External Objects.

Note: I'm using a custom Lightning Connect adapter.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought external objects don't have Id column. Can you try removing Id column from the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing directly on the server .

I would ask below questions

1)What version of eclipse are you in ?

2)The other reason can be many times we forget to make object in deployment mode and it is still in "In development" mode ,double check the same .